# BUILD FAILED: Attempt to copy file to [path]. Java (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

**I'm tired of searching for answers, my problem is:**

I want to create an executable file, I am working on a large program, and I encounter this problem, I did not find a solution, I created a new program to look for the problem, the new program does not have any code, just a line in order to show 'Hello Word' and added a picture in another package, And again encountered the same problem:

```
    ant -f 'MyPath'\\New -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: 'MyPath'\New\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory 'MyPath'\New\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: 'MyPath'\New\build
Updating property file: 'MyPath'\New\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: 'MyPath'\New\build\classes
Created dir: 'MyPath'\New\build\empty
Created dir: 'MyPath'\New\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to 'MyPath'\New\build\classes
Copying 1 file to 'MyPath'\New\build\classes
Attempt to copy 'MyPath'\New\src\pic\1.png to 'MyPath'\New\build\classes\pic\1.png using NIO Channels failed due to 'MyPath'\New\build\classes\pic\1.png (Accès refusé)'.  Falling back to streams.
    'MyPath'\New\nbproject\build-impl.xml:931: Failed to copy 'MyPath'\New\src\pic\1.png to 'MyPath'\New\build\classes\pic\1.png due to java.io.FileNotFoundException 'MyPath'\New\build\classes\pic\1.png (Accès refusé)
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.2 , Sys : Windows 10.

Comment: I would need to see the code in question to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a file/folder permissions problem. Your user does not have the rights to make changes to certain files/folders involved in the build process, so neither does Netbeans. You can validate this by running that ant command as root through the command line - it should suddenly work.

I solved the problem on mac by changing the group permissions for the parent folder listed in the error message and adding my user to said group.

I'm not an expert when it comes to permissions on Windows, so I shouldn't try to tell you how to do the same there, but you could reference something like this - https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/ - for help in achieving the same thing.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24216178)

Comment: @nircraft Thought it might help though - should I have added this as a comment rather?

Comment: yes, that's what you should do if it's not an answer.

Comment: @nircraft I did attempt to research what a valid SO answer was before posting this.. this place is intimidating enough that I had a 30-minute debate with myself regarding whether to even bother. But at the end of it I realised that the information I could give is helpful and I'd want to have found it if I came looking. "Change file/folder permissions" is literally the solution to this problem and I gave as much extra information as possible. According to this post - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer - my answer is indeed an answer.

Comment: sounds good! as long it's well written and helpful, you are good!